# Hide the answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, spoilers

I think all the answers should be hidden until the user clicks something, like a "Show answers" button. With a short question with short answers like this:

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/7-oranges-given-to-7-children

It would be a very helpful feature.

Comment: And comments. I maintain the Empuzzler userscript Emrakul linked below, and I wrote it to hide comments as they tend to spoil the puzzle as frequently as the answers do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Empuzzler: A user script for hiding comments and answers until you want to see them](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1316/empuzzler-a-user-script-for-hiding-comments-and-answers-until-you-want-to-see-t)

Answer (score 3):

You can install [this userscript](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1316/empuzzler-a-user-script-for-hiding-comments-and-answers-until-you-want-to-see-t), called Empuzzler, which will hide answers until you are ready to show them.

Comment: Suppose I'm an Opera user. I should not have to install a third-party plugin to make the site useable.

Comment: @Almo When making a feature request, it's helpful to avoid huge exaggerations like asserting the site is unusable without this feature. It's not unusable at all - it's just really inconvenient, or not as good as it could be.

Comment: I don't find a puzzle site where I have to work actively not to see solutions before I even finish reading the question as nearing unusable. It's not fullfilling its purpose, unless it's just supposed to be some list of puzzles and answers. I was under the impression you should be able to come here and get puzzles you'd like to try to solve as well. But if the answer is starting you in the face right there, it's hard to try to solve it.

Comment: @Almo I believe you may be mistaken about the fundamental purpose of Stack Exchange sites. While this might first appear contradictory, we are not actually here to _provide_ puzzles to answer, but rather to discuss puzzle creation, design, and solution. If you're looking for puzzles to solve, I suggest looking through some unanswered questions, and, perhaps, answering them!

Comment: If this is a *really* hard feature to implement, fine. But it feels like rationalizations are being made to explain why a feature that makes sense is bad.

Comment: @Almo I think that is the case. As a web developer myself, I doubt that it's an easy thing to change; it's pretty fundamental to how SE works in general that the answers are visible - for any other QA site, that's the whole point. Puzzling is somewhat unique, and if the underlying SE platform is built around making answers visible, there would logically be no need for something to hide answers by default

Answer (score 2):

Spoilers can now be added. Just put ! marks after the usual > marks that appear in blockquote formatting.

> Example

And the code is:

```
>! Example
```

(Status-completed tag pending..)